# Why are two network calls being made, when fetch in setState?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, setstate

When I use fetch in setState the function makes two network requests, but I expect one request.

Why is this happening and how to prevent it?

```
import React from 'react';

class TestFetch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {

    this.setState(() => {

      fetch('http://example.com/', {
        mode: 'no-cors'
      })
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Test </button>
    )
  }
}

export default TestFetch
```

Another version with setState in the fetch. Now I have one network call, but two values in my state after one click:

```
import React from 'react';

class TestFetch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      'newItems': []
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {

    fetch('http://example.com/', {
      mode: 'no-cors'
    })
      .then(data => {

        this.setState((state) => {
          state.newItems.push("value")
        })

        console.log(this.state)
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Test </button>
    )
  }
}

export default TestFetch
```

Ok, basically it has this effect in this example as well:

```
import React from 'react';

class TestFetch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      'newItems': []
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => {
      state.newItems.push("value")
    })
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Test </button>
    )
  }
}

export default TestFetch
```

Comment: My guess would be you are rendering your app into a `React.StrictMode` component. See [Detecting unintentional side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) Question though... why are you applying asynchronous logic in the state updater function and not in an ***actual*** lifecycle method or regular callback? Seems a good way to have a broken app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening...

My guess would be you are rendering your app into a `React.StrictMode` component. See [Detecting unintentional side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by **intentionally double-invoking** the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - **State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)**
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`

In other words, the `setState` is called twice by React to help you find unintentional side-effects, like the double fetching.

> ...and how to prevent it?

Just don't do side-effects in the `setState` callback function. You likely meant to do the `fetch` and in the Promise chain update state.

```
handleClick() {
  fetch('http://example.com/', {
    mode: 'no-cors'
  })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState( ......); // <-- update state from response data
    });
}
```

#### Update

> Another version with setState in the fetch. Now I have one network
> call, but two values in my state after one click:

In your updated code you are mutating the state object. `Array.prototype.push` updates the array by adding the new element to the end of the array and returns the new length of the array.

[Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
this.setState(state => {
  state.newItems.push("value") // <-- mutates the state object
})
```

I believe you see 2 new items added for the same reason as above. When updating arrays in state you need to return a ***new*** array reference.

You can use [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to add the new value *and* return a new array:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  newItems: prevState.newItems.concat("value"),
});
```

Another common pattern is to shallow copy the previous state array into a new array and append the new value:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  newItems: [...prevState.newItems, "value"],
});
```

Additionally, once you sort out your state updates, the console log of the state won't work because React state updates are asynchronously processed. Log the updated state from the [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState !== this.state) {
    console.log(this.state);
  }
}
```

Comment: But in my case, I need to know the data of the state before making a request. Since I add a component to the state and after that, depending on the type of component, I make a request to save this data in the database. How can I get the data from the state before the request?

Comment: And thanks for the clarification, I was not aware of this type of React behavior.

Comment: @demjanich Component state is locally global within React components. Access via `this.state`. Inside the `handleClick` callback you can access `this.state.<value>` and check what you need before making any network requests. Perhaps it would be more beneficial to update your question with a more representative code example for the issue you are trying to solve for. Can you clarify what you mean by "add a component to the state"? If you are enqueueing a state update and need to reference the updated state then you'll need to move the fetch logic to `componentDidUpdate` and use a condition.

Comment: >Can you clarify what you mean by "add a component to the state"?

It's not a component, just some ID's and values related to the component.

I updated my question. I added a new version with setState inside of fetch. Now I have only one network call, but two values in state after one click. How to prevent that? And I don't want to switch off the strict mode, because it looks useful.

Comment: @demjanich Unintentional side-effect is state mutation, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do api call in setState.. take state variable and store api response data in it and use state variable when ever it's required.

```
 import React from 'react';
    
    class TestFetch extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {appData: null};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }
    
      handleClick() {
    
     fetch('http://example.com/', {
            mode: 'no-cors'
          })
            .then(data => {
              console.log(data)
     this.setState(() => {appData: data});
            });
       
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Test </button>
        )
      }
    }
    
    export default TestFetch
```

Comment: But in my case, I need to know the data of the state before making a request. Since I add a component to the state and after that, depending on the type of component, I make a request to save this data in the database. How can I get the data from the state before the request?